# Is it possible to browse my iTunes backup files?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I use to store **older backups** of my iPad, iPod and iPhone made using iTunes.

So, as long as some data (i.e: photos) is **stored** on one of these backups, I feel free to **delete it on the devices**.

If, in a future, I need only some specific data (say music, document, video, email... etc), may I **access to the backup** to...? :

- **Browse** it to see what is there inside.
- **Extract** some specific info.

If yes, what **kind of data** could be extracted? :

- **Only files** like photos, videos or documents?
- Or is it possible to dig for some more **complex data** like SMSs, notes, emails, phone lists... etc?

Remember that I don't want to restore any backup. I just want to *look inside* it.  Also, I don't want recommendations on software that reads the files. I'm looking for how to understand what's on the filesystem.

Comment: We are getting some spam on this. Would you mind editing this down. Perhaps asking where the files are stored or asking how to access one specific item would be best. If you want software recommendations - late make that a proper request or rule it out. This is a honeypot for people pushing software for the task of automating the process of harvesting backup files.

Comment: @bmike, I don't understand where is the problem on asking for some `backup files browser`. Why should it generate any spam? The question is not about "where the files are stored", nor "access one specific item" (whatever that could be). I am not asking for "software recommendations", but for any method to "access to the backup to browse or extract" my data.

Comment: Perfect. If you want to edit that into the question we can remove the hold. I'm not deleting the question so it only needs to remain open if you want more answers. Asking a more specific follow on question would work well too. Thanks!

Comment: Edited, @bmike. I hope the question to be more clear now.

Comment: Now the problem is all the answers are what you say you don't want (i.e. software recommendations.) I'll ask the other moderators to look  - we might just choose to close this and let you ask a follow on question if the spam keeps coming for recommending software to do the job...

Comment: @bmike, all the answers are what you say I don't want, as long as you changed my text `I am not necessarily asking for "software recommendations". Any method to "access to the backup to browse or extract" my data could be worth`. I still don't know what the problem in answering a software recommendation is. All the rest of Stack Exchange forums do the same: you ask for a way to solve your problem, and the answer could be commands, software, hardware, hacks, or whatever. Even here the answer is some internet-controlled robotic arm to push a simple button: http://superuser.com/a/319880/268923 .

Comment: If I get your (original) question and the comments right, you are looking for a way to inspect an iOS backup and (if needed) extract certain items (photos etc.) from it. This is a question which has come up before and already has the usual software recommendation as answers (and the usual spam suspects which you can't see because they got deleted). So if we don't want to close this question here as a duplicate, can you describe more specifically on how your question differs from the existing ones on the same topic (e.g. why the usual set of software recommendation doesn't help you here)?

Comment: Also please keep in mind that the various SE sites have slightly different on-topic/off-topic rules, not only regarding software recommendation. Based on past experience, the community on AD tends to close overly broad questions for software recommendation.

Comment: @patrix : it is OK for me to mark this question as duplicate: it will still be useful as long as duplicates are linked between them. Concerning the spam issue: I don't know how to solve it; maybe the SE rules will enough: any spam will be flagged and deleted. Concerning the `slightly different on-topic/off-topic rules` that make this site not allowing software answers, I suggest for the exact words to be quoted, like «Closed due to `question searching for answers not allowed` rule».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! It is possible to view the contents of backups. There are several programs you can use, the one I use is [iExplorer v3](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).

You can view and extract:

- Messages
- Contacts
- Voicemail (though I have not tried this)
- Call history
- Notes
- Safari (bookmarks and history)
- Calendar
- More if you are willing to dig into folders

The free version allows you to view the contents, but has restrictions on extracting them.

There is also [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/) which does:

- Photos
- Recordings
- Again, perhaps more

This is also a free / paid app, so have a look at what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A good answer. `iExplorer` does not extract WhatsApp messages, but it seems `iPhone Backup Extractor` does. How sad they are not open source :-( .

Comment: https://github.com/horrorho/InflatableDonkey is open source tool for downloading iOS 9 backups, see also https://github.com/hackappcom/iloot for iOS < 9

Answer (score 0):

Even when suggestions from @OrangePeel are good, if you don't want to pay to browse WhatsApp conversations, this is your best bet: [FonePaw's iPhone Data Recovery](http://www.fonepaw.com/iphone-data-recovery/).

The trial version (15 days) seems to have full features, not like [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/), that only extracts 4 lines from WhatsApp.

The rest of options are **very complete** too:

[image]

Comment: this is  NOT FREE

Comment: Indeed, it is not free (neither is iPhone Backup Extractor). So I referred in my answer «The trial version». But you can have 15 days of full featured functionality, that, for many (i.e: extracting some specific data) could be enough.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Not anymore, unfortunately