# How to view iPhone backup contents WITHOUT a 3rd party app?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

Most solutions that have you [viewing contents of an iPhone backup have you using a 3rd party solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188937/218). There are many such products out there, and not all of them are free.

According to at least one user, it [seems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300203/how-can-i-delete-a-certificate-that-got-restored-from-a-backup-under-ios-10-11#comment509721_310041) there is a way to view the contents without a 3rd party app:

> This solution worked as a charm! **I manually found the TrustStore.sqlite3 in my backup (I don't trust those apps that do that)**, then followed your instructions. – Ian Dec 17, 2019 at 21:53

However, even though I have an unencrypted backup, when I try to look at the contents of the backup, its content are split/garbled in many different files/folders like:

- 00
- 0a
- 0b
- etc.

How do I manually view the contents of these files **WITHOUT** a 3rd party app?

(An acceptable solution could also point to code that I could manually run to un-garble these files)

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like a sparse disk image, the backup file format is actually pretty simple. The only difficult part is figuring out the actual file name of each file since Apple uses a `fileID` of random numbers/letters instead of an actual file name. You can figure out the file name by examining the `Manifest.db` file, though:

1. Create a local backup (only tested with unencrypted backup).
2. Open the `Backup` folder.
3. Open the `Manifest.db` in a SQLLite viewer.
4. Find the file you're looking for (e.g. `TrustStore.sqlite3`) under the `relativePath` column. Look at the value in its `fileID` (this will be a random list of numbers and characters).
5. In your backup, find the corresponding `fileID`, and rename it to the name you saw in the `relativePath` column (e.g. `TrustStore.sqlite3`).

   E.g. if the `fileID` says `03ab1c2a…`, look for the file under the `03` subfolder in your backup.
6. You can now use the file as you normally would. There is no conversion needed, just a simple file rename!

This was tested on macOS 12 and iOS 16.